# How to bind with textfield in vaadin 8?

Tags: data-binding, vaadin8

I am migrating my application from vaadin 7 to 8. I am having trouble in understanding how to bind the object to a text field.
In vaadin 7, I have the following:

```
public void setProject(Project value, boolean hasScreenedReferences)
{
    this.project = value;

    TextField projectNameTextField = new TextField();
    projectNameTextField.setStyleName("step_one_project_name_text");
    projectNameTextField.setPlaceholder("Review Name");

    // Bind the project UI components to the new object 
     BeanItem<Project> projectBean = new BeanItem<Project>(value);
     projectNameTextField.projectNameTextField(projectBean.getItemProperty("name"));
     projectNameTextField.addValidator(new BeanValidator(Project.class, "name"));
  .......
}
```

Now as I mentioned I couldn't understand how it would work in vaadin 8, I tried the following after reading some online forums

```
    // Bind the project UI components to the new object
    Binder<Project> binder = new Binder<Project>();
    binder.bind(projectNameTextField, Project::getName, Project::setName);
```

I am not sure if it's correct, as I don't know how would I use the "value" in above line of codes and how would I add the validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a validator this way:

```
Binder<Project> binder = new Binder<>();
binder.forField(projectNameTextField)
      .withValidator(new StringLengthValidator("Invalida length!", 5, null))
      .bind(Project::getName, Project::setName);
```

To make the fields show the values from your `Project` object call `readBean`:

```
binder.readBean(project);
```

And then you can execute validation for example:

```
if (!binder.writeBeanIfValid(project)) {
       Notification.show("Invalid!!", Notification.Type.WARNING_MESSAGE);
       return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Vaadin docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/framework/v8/datamodel/datamodel-forms.html) for binding data to forms. The code example show what you need: You can call `forField` on the `Binder` to get a builder that allows to add validators and converters, and finally `bind` to the appropriate bean property. To make the fields show the values from your `Project` object call `readBean` on the binder. `writeBean` allows to write the field data into your `Project` object.